# UTF-8 Encoding and Decoding in c#

Tags: c#

I Searched for " How to Encode the data in utf-8 format". Regarding this I got the best result is following:

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
String unicodeString = "ABCD";
// Encode the string.
Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
// Decode bytes back to string.
String decodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);
```

But the Problem is when I see the encoded data I found that is not more than ASCII code.
can any one help me to improve my knowledge.
For example as I passed "ABCD " it gets converted into `65,66,67,68....` I think this is not utf-8

Comment: Strings in C# are already UTF-16, why do you need to convert it to UTF-8?

Comment: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec "A" is 65. No problem here.

Comment: ASCII maps directly to UTF-8 without any change. You'll need a non-ASCII character to see any difference, for example, `é` or `€`

Comment: `Byte` is a numerical type so an array of `Byte` is expected to contains numbers, surprising would be to see something different :)

Comment: @rakeshgupta "I think this is not utf-8" - you think wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 is [backwards compatible with ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) of course. You should test with some characters that are not included in ASCII.

If you program in C# the strings are already encoded in UTF-16. You will not see anything Special there. If you want to see something you should try to compare the LENGTH of the Byte[] when you encode the string into different Encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Wikipedia article on UTF8: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

From there:

> Backward compatibility: One-byte codes are used only for the ASCII
> values 0 through 127. In this case the UTF-8 code has the same value
> as the ASCII code. The high-order bit of these codes is always 0. This
> means that UTF-8 can be used for parsers expecting 8-bit extended
> ASCII even if they are not designed for UTF-8.

The point here is that for anything that would be ASCII 0-127 in UTF8 it's the same.  You need to try more extended characters (an example in the article is the Euro symbol) to see how it's different.  Or try an ASCII value greater than 127 and you'll see it different.

Comment: Thanks for your nice and easy description